# SQL Database Design for SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design, ssis, relational-database

OK my first question so here goes.

Currently users are using a huge Access Application. They wanted a web application with some functionality based off of the Access data and with some modifications.

Ok no problem. I used the Access to SQL migration assistant to convert the data over and then wrote some SSIS packages which are executed from the web end to allow the application to be updated as needed. All here is good.

Here is where I am kind of stumped. There are 2 types of imports, quarterly and yearly. The quarterly is fine but the yearly import is causing issues. The yearly import can be for an adopted budget or for a proposed budget (each is held in a separate Access db). I have one SSIS package for each type of yearly import. The table where the information goes is as follows..

```
CREATE TABLE Budget
(
    BudgetID           uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    ProjectNumber      int NOT NULL,
    SubProjectNumber   varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    FiscalYearBegin    int NOT NULL,
    FiscalYearEnd      int NOT NULL,
    Sequence           int NULL,
    QuarterImportDate  datetime NULL,
    ProposedBudget     money NULL,
    AdoptedBudget      money NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Budget PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        BudgetID ASC
    ),

    CONSTRAINT uc_Budget UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        ProjectNumber ASC,
        SubProjectNumber ASC,
        FiscalYearBegin ASC,
        FiscalYearEnd ASC,
        Sequence ASC
    )
)
```

Also, there can be multiple versions of the budget for the specific year in terms of `Project`, `SubProject`, `FiscalYearBegin`, and `FiscalYearEnd`. Thats is why there is a sequence number.

So the problem becomes, since I have 2 different SSIS packages, each of which is an update statement on 1 specific column (either `ProposedBudget` or `AdoptedBudget`), I have no effective way of keeping track of the correct sequence.

Please let me know if I can make this any clearer, and any advice would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: What is the difference between BudgetId and Sequence?

Comment: BudgetID is just a uniqueidentifier (NEWID) for that row. The sequence was meant to be the version for that year. Example you are doing your first import for FiscalYear 2010/2011. Every project and subproject will have FiscalYearBegin = 2010, FiscalYearEnd= = 2011 and Sequence = 0. The next import will have Sequence = 1

Comment: So you import the ProposedBudget as Sequence 1, then AdoptedBudget is a seperate update to the same row, with sequence 1?  Do you know for sure that each proposedbudget and adopted budget are one-to-one?  Is it possible that there might be more proposedbudgets or adoptedbudgets such that you have some sequences with only one?

Comment: Exactly, I import the ProposedBudget as Sequence1 and then the AdoptedBudget is a separate update to that same row with sequence1. I do not have the update statement for that 2nd Update perfected yet. Here is the thing the ProposedBudget will change many times however the Adopted will be the same for that year, so every sequence per FiscalYearBegin and FiscalYearEnd will have the same adopted just every new sequence will have a different proposed theoretically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will get you the next item with an empty AdoptedBudget, but I think you will need a cursor when there are multiple AdoptedBudgets.  I was thinking of doing a nested subquery with an update, but that won't work when there are multiple AdoptedBudgets.  It sounds like in the source application they should be selecting a ProposedBudget whenever they add the AdoptedBudget so that a relationship can be created.  This way it is clear which AdoptedBudget goes with which ProposedBudget, and it would be a simple join.  I have almost the same scenario, but the difference is that I don't keep all the versions.  I only have to keep the most current "ProposedBudget" and most current "AdoptedBudget".  It's a little bit more difficult trying to sequence them all.

```
  --get the smallest SequenceId with an unfilled AdoptedBudget
  Select min(SequenceID), 
    ProjectNumber, 
    FiscalYearBegin, 
    SubProjectNumber --any other fields needed for the join
  From Budgets b
  Where AdoptedBudget is null
  Group By 
    ProjectNumber, 
    FiscalYearBegin, 
    SubProjectNumber --any other fields needed for the join


--This won't work I don't believe
Update Budgets
Set AdoptedBudget = BudgetAmount
From Budgets b
Inner Join SourceAdoptedBudgets ab on 
  b.ProjectNumber = ab.ProjectNumber
  b.FiscalYearBegin = ab.FiscalYearBegin
  b.FiscalYearEnd = ab.FiscalYearEnd
Inner Join
(
  --get the smallest SequenceId with an unfilled AdoptedBudget
  Select min(SequenceID), 
    ProjectNumber, 
    FiscalYearBegin, 
    SubProjectNumber --any other fields needed for the join
  From Budgets b
  Where AdoptedBudget is null
  Group By 
    ProjectNumber, 
    FiscalYearBegin, 
    SubProjectNumber --any other fields needed for the join
) as nextBudgets
on --the join fields again
```

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines of finding the Null for the AdoptedBudget Update Statement. Just could not put the pieces together. From the application they do pick which type of import (Adropted,Proposed) they are doing. Correct me if I am wrong but checking this way would force the user to upload Proposed first and then Adopted?

Comment: Yes, they would have to upload the proposed first.  I would do a count grouped by the key fields for adopted and proposed with a join and see how often the counts don't match up.  It would seem like someone might uploads 3 proposed budgets and then finally one adopted budget.  Which of the proposed budgets does it go with?  I would get rid of the Proposed/Adopted Budget fields, and instead have a single BudgetAmount and VersionType indicating it is Proposed or Adopted.  You could select from both sources, union them, then a partitioned row_number field to generate the sequence on importdate

Comment: I thought about this at the beginning and this is what I ended up doing so thank you for putting me along the right track. I put one single BudgetAmount field and had an identifier for Proposed/Adopted. I am pretty amazed you got my explanation right on! You totally rock.. I work with 0 technical people all day so this was a nice comfort zone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this using the BudgetType.  Of course you'd probably create a code table for these or a IsAdopted bit field.  But you get the idea.

```
Select 
budgets.*
,row_number() over(partition by 
   ProjectNumber
  ,SubProjectNumber
  ,FiscalYearBegin
  ,FiscalYearEnd 
   order by QuarterImportDate) as SequenceNumber
From
(
  Select
  ProjectNumber
  ,SubProjectNumber
  ,FiscalYearBegin
  ,FiscalYearEnd
  ,QuarterImportDate
  ,'Proposed' as BudgetType
  ,ProposedBudget as Budget
  From sourceProposed

  Union

  Select
  ProjectNumber
  ,SubProjectNumber
  ,FiscalYearBegin
  ,FiscalYearEnd
  ,QuarterImportDate
  ,'Adopted' as BudgetType
  ,AdoptedBudget as Budget
  From sourceAdopted
) as budgets
```